# ESC / POS Thermal Printer - How to set line spacing inside page mode?

Tags: thermal-printer, escpos

I have an Sweda (same as SAM4S) thermal printer that supports ESC/POS.

The issue is that I am not able to set line spacing inside the page mode. Here is what I do:

- Enter page mode

  {ESC, 0x4C}
- Set line spacing

  {ESC, 0x33, (byte)48}
- Set area Size

  ```
  send((byte)(x & 255), (byte)(x >> 8 & 255),
        (byte)(y & 255), (byte)(y >> 8 & 255),
        (byte)(width & 255), (byte)(width>> 8 & 255),
        (byte)(height & 255), (byte)(height >> 8 & 255));
  ```
- Sent text and line feeds (LF)

According to the docs, line spacing should take effect on page mode, but it's not working. Only works outside "page mode".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the following for the description at the EPSON site of each control sequence.
The corresponding page is in Japanese.

[ESC L](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos_ja/index.php?content_id=193)
[ESC 3](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos_ja/index.php?content_id=20)
[ESC W](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos_ja/index.php?content_id=56)
[LF](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos_ja/index.php?content_id=56)

On EPSON printers, it is stated that you can set line spacing settings for page mode like your question.
But you are not using EPSON printers.

Please contact your printer manufacturer to find out if your printer supports this specification and what to do if it does not support the specification.